# Draw a serpent with "x" and "o"

Tags: arrays, integer, drawing

We want to draw a snake with the following characteristics:

The snake will have N undulations.

Each ripple will start horizontally and extend from left to right, then top to bottom, then right to left, and finally top to bottom again.

The width of the horizontal segments will be X.

The length between horizontal segments will be Y characters.

The body of the snake must be represented by 'x' characters.

The head of the snake will be the last part drawn and will be represented by the character 'o'.

Entrance
The input consists of 3 lines, each with N, X, Y respectively, such that

1 <= N, X, Y <= 2000000000.".

Exit
A rectangle of dimension X (width), Y (length), whose edges have “x” and the interior spaces “o”.

Examples

Entry Example 1

1
4
2
Output Example 1

xxxx
x
x
xxxx
x
o

Entry Example 2

3
2
1
Output Example 2

xx
x
xx
x
xx
x
xx
x
xx
x
xx
o

I can't even imagine a resolve to this problem, then I don't have anything.